# Cassandra timeuuid to datetime

Tags: cassandra

I want to get **datetime** from Cassandra **timeuuid** using php.
 
i tried it 

$timeuuid = 'ebadad30-d625-11e5-bab2-b9c665f5f7cd'; 
$date = new Cassandra/Timeuuid::Time($timeuuid);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toDate() functions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) that are builded inside Cassandra

For example `SELECT toDate(columTimeUUID) FROM YourTable` will give you a date formated as : `YYYY-MM-DD`

However, it works for Cassandra versions greater than 2.2

Comment: yes, it works but i want to get it before execute query for matching time in my cql statment.

Comment: He asked for datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT toTimestamp(columTimeUUID) FROM YourTable
```

For more details visit : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html